# getParameterByName return null value in JavaScript in Phonegap with iphone

Tags: cordova

I am new in phonegap. I had passed URL. It is return null.
and used function for get URL value and call getParameterByName('label')

```
<a href="add-personal-info.html?label=lbl_alias" data-transition="slide">

function getParameterByName(name)

{  
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if(results == null)
      return "";
    else
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

}
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if I understand your question but if you want to get the value of your "label" parameter you can simply use :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var label_value = window.location.search.replace("?", "");
    label_value  = label_value.replace("label=", "");
});
```

You have to modifiy this code if you have more than only one parameter in your URL.

Hope this helps ! Bye !